# Is there A way to execute/reference Native code in the browser using React Js?

Tags: c++, reactjs, native, webassembly, edgejs

We have a code base written in C++ and a code base written in C#.net that works as expected, however I am tasked to execute/reference this code in a react application at runtime, I read about WebAssembly and Edge js, got an idea about the matter but I am lacking the details and the time. So Could any one share some insights and knowledge about this please. Ultimately the native code needs to be executed in client side...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: Use Emscripten.

Comment: @BumsikKim thanks , but didn't know how to install it and use it in a React Js application/environment ... any help would be infinetly appreciated :D

Comment: This emscripten converts a C++ file into JS using webassembly: https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html . Things such as native file system access can be facilitated using JS. As far as converting the JS into React, I believe there are a few tools online somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

##### React and C++

I have been successfully using WASM in conjunction with React for running C++ code on the client in production. In my case, the C++ codebase is used for computationally expensive message parsing. To give you some context, the flow is as follows:

1. I have some raw binary data in a JS typed array that needs parsing.
2. I pass the binary data to WASM using emscripten. Note that this adds some overhead as detailed [here](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/5519)
3. I use my C++ codebase compiled with emscripten to parse the raw data.
4. I create a JS object using emscripten's [embind](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html) and return it to my JS code.

Please note that my C++ code does not need access to any file system, sockets, network, etc. and is single-threaded.

Some things I really appreciate using emscripten and WASM:

1. emscripten is well documented and provides user-friendly error messages.
2. With the right [tools](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/wasm-debugging-2020/) you can debug WASM conveniently alongside your JS codebase.
3. emscripten's build pipeline allows for really fast iterations. I managed to wire up emscripten with React in way that basically gives me hot reloading for my C++ code.

I've seen several POC's out there that integrate emscripten with React, for example:

- https://github.com/9oelM/emscripten-cplusplus-webpack-example
- https://github.com/viroulep/emscripten-webpack-cra

Let me know what WASM features your codebase requires and I'll see if I can point out more fitting examples.